# Why can't I use multiple yield requests in Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, yield

I am pretty new to Scrapy and was just wondering why can't I use multiple yield statements?

```
import scrapy

class CourseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'course'
start_urls = ['link.example']

def parse(self, response):
    syllabus = response.css('div#course_syllabus')
    title = response.css('title::text').get()
    image = syllabus.css('img::attr(src)').get()
    image_desc = syllabus.css('p::text')[1].get()
    desc = syllabus.css('p::text')[10].get()
    for i in (title, image, image_desc):
        yield {'course' : i}
        
    yield {'course_overview' : desc}
```

So when outputting to CSV file I got my 'course' column with title, image and image_desc values, however it doesn't add 'course_overview' column to the csv at all. I only need 1 value so didn't include it in the for loop. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple yields possible for multiple pipelines but here you are trying to add all in 1 yield. If you have only one item in for loop and if you want to add 1 more column calls "course_overview" you can use yield like this:

```
import scrapy

class CourseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'course'
start_urls = ['link.example']

def parse(self, response):
    syllabus = response.css('div#course_syllabus')
    title = response.css('title::text').get()
    image = syllabus.css('img::attr(src)').get()
    image_desc = syllabus.css('p::text')[1].get()
    desc = syllabus.css('p::text')[10].get()
    item = scrapy.Item()
    for i in (title, image, image_desc):
        item['course'] = i
        
    item['course_overview'] = desc
    yield item
```

Instead of double yield, you can handle multiple columns with scrapy item.

Answer (score 0):

To create single cvs file for output, you have to use single yield request. to add another column try as follows:

PS: Your request url is also incorrect, Please correct it using proper scheme.

```
import scrapy
    
class CourseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'course'
    start_urls = ['link.example']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        syllabus = response.css('div#course_syllabus')
        title = response.css('title::text').get()
        image = syllabus.css('img::attr(src)').get()
        image_desc = syllabus.css('p::text')[1].get()
        desc = syllabus.css('p::text')[10].get()
        for i in (title, image, image_desc):
            yield {
                  'course' : i,
                  'course_overview' : desc}
```